# Log4j-2.6.2 Basic Configurator is not configuring the logging levels

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I was trying to implement a basic configurator via the following code

```
package com.myapp.loggingutilities;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class LoggingUtilitiesApplication {
    static Logger currentLogger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingUtilitiesApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        currentLogger.debug("Application Started here");
        LoggerUtilityModel bar = new LoggerUtilityModel();
        bar.doIt();
        currentLogger.debug("Application ended");

    }
}
```

The class def for `bar` is

```
package com.myapp.loggingutilities;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerUtilityModel {
    static Logger modelLogger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerUtilityModel.class);

    public void doIt() {
        modelLogger.debug("OPPS! DID IT AGAIN");
    }

}
```

I am using Log4j2 and the distribution was taken [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/logging/log4j/2.6.2/apache-log4j-2.6.2-bin.zip). I am always getting the SLF4J bridge error when I have the Log4j-to-slf4j and implementation jars in build path:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:59)
```

When I removed them, it was okay. But the log messages were not being printed

I thought `BasicConfigurator` ought to be configuring the root logger for DEBUG so all of my log statements should go through (i.e. anything on or above DEBUG level). But I cannot see any log messages on the console when I run the application. Something I have missed?

Comment: I just ran your code and got according messages in the console with `DEBUG` level.

Comment: @DimaSan        I happened to remove the slf4j binding jars from my build path since they were complaining about conflicts - did you do that too?

Comment: I think the problem is in missing `slf4j` jars because I ran your code with Spring Boot that already includes it.

Comment: @DimaSan       I ran the application on it's own and the binding is not working when I have SLF4J jars on the path. I don't intend to run with Spring.

Comment: Again I just created a new Java project and add the only one jar [Apache Log4j 1.2.17](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17) to my build path and it works.

Comment: @DimaSan       I am not using 1.2, I am using 2 see my question and tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122631/discussion-between-ha9u63ar-and-dimasan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BasicConfigurator` is a log4j 1.2 class and cannot be used to configure Log4j 2. Basically, everything in the `org.apache.log4j` package is Log4j 1.2 (old) and everything in the `org.apache.logging.log4j` namespace is for Log4j 2.

If you are interested in programmatic configuration of Log4j 2, please see [the manual page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). Personally I find the new simplified XML configuration file format easiest to work with.

The behavior you are seeing (only console logging at ERROR level) is Log4j 2's "default configuration", which is what it does if it can't find a configuration file and hasn't been manually configured.

Comment: @RemkoPompa       Thanks for the annswer. But it still doesn't make sense why 1.2 had DEBUG and 2.x has ERROR. I was expecting this reason to be documented somewhere. Also,

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the LEVEL set for log4j2.6.2. As per Apache's Log4J-2.6.2 docs, all the default log messages are set for DEBUG.

Also, you CANNOT change the logging level using root logger. You need to change it per logger. Everything is defaulted to ERROR.